# Using XPATH to extract input value from google maps inputbox

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I would like to extract input value(s) from Google maps inputbox using xpath. 
For eg: for these [inputs](https://www.google.fi/maps/dir/Bay+St,+Toronto,+ON,+Canada/Toronto+Pearson+International+Airport+(YYZ),+Silver+Dart+Drive,+Mississauga,+ON,+Canada/@43.6728321,-79.7808692,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x882b34ca5b2882df:0x102e24ef596a0a4a!2m2!1d-79.3843645!2d43.6572984!1m5!1m1!1s0x882b394ac02dd491:0xb41d5de9c4030ec5!2m2!1d-79.6248197!2d43.6777176!3e0)

So I should get *"Toronto Pearson International Airport"*

When I do `(//input)[2]/text()`. I donot get any value.
I have also tried `(//input[@class="tactile-searchbox-input"])[4]` which shows destination("Toronto Pearson International Airport") in "value" property when I check in chrome console.

What would be the right approach here to extract value from input box.

Comment: If I have to do only within selenium, I guess question will be duplicate. I am looking for pure XPath solution to extract value.

Comment: There is no pure XPath solution. Selenium support XPath that returns WebElement only

Comment: So xpath cannot extract properties like "value" that we see in chrome element?

Comment: XPath can extract attribute value, but not in Selenium: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input').get_attribute('value')` (OK), `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input/@value')` (not OK)

Comment: so in chrome `$x("(//input)[1]/@value")` does not return any value